Icono en Sitio Web interno que permita el acceso a una carpeta del servidor de TrueNAS
Tengo un servidor de TrueNAS en dónde tenemos archivos, debo de hacer una página y me piden que en dicho lugar haya un icono para acceder a ciertas carpetas del servidor, pero por seguridad los navegadores actuales no permiten esto.
Sin embargo he encontrado que se pueden realizar si configuro el servidor, no obstante, este ya ha sido configurado, permitiendo a las personas acceder a las carpetas con los documentos por medio del explorador de archivos. Todas las computadoras de la empresa poseen Windows, he visto que una opción puede ser la siguiente:
    function openFolder() {
    var folderURL = "smb://servidor/ruta_de_la_carpeta";
    window.open(folderURL);
    }

La otra opción que vi es hacer una configuración en Truenas para convertir las direcciones en Http: para que así coloque en el href="http://servidor/ruta_de_la_carpeta", pero no tengo nada de experiencia con TrueNAS
